# Dijkstra's Algorithm- Two equal weights, one leads to a shorter path. What to do?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

I am confused about this situation that happened to me as I was trying to solve a shortest path problem using Dijkstra's Algorithm.

'$s$' is the starting point and '$t$' is finish.

When I reach to the point where my Visited set is $S_5=\{s,d,a,e,b,h\}$, I have two options to continue from to the next Current vertex, they are both equal and from what I have been reading, when you get to a situation where you have two equal weights you choose arbitrarily. The problem is, when I choose arbitrarily here, one path is shorter than the other:

If I choose: $S_7=\{s,d,a,e,b,h,g,t\}$, then I get $l(t)=12$.
If I choose: $S_7=\{s,d,a,e,b,h,f,t\}$, then I get $l(t)=9$.

How do I know which one to choose from when I get equal weights? because it obviously affects the whole path.

[image]

Comment: Are $a,b,c,\ldots$ the labels of nodes other than $s,t$ from left to right?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I forget to mention. The next right after s is a and to its right is b and so on...

Comment: I don't understand the question. At that point, you have three vertices that will be at a distance of $8$ from $s$ to add, $g$, reached from $b$ in $2$, and $f$ and $j$ are both reached in $3$ from $e$. So you add these to the queue, in whichever order you like. After that, the next closest vertex is $i$, reachable in $3$ from $h$ for a total distance of $9$. Then $t$ is at the front of the queue, reachable in $2$ from $g$ for a total distance of $10$. Dijkstra ends.

Answer (score 1):

$t$ should not be a member of your $S_7$ in any case.

Steps 6, 7, and 8 will add nodes $f$, $g$ and $j$ to to the working set, in some arbitrary order, because all are at a distance of $8$ from the starting node. So these nodes will always get added before you start considering things at larger distance.

If you add $g$ in step 6, you don't immediately proceed to connect $g$ to $t$ -- that must only happen in a later step. And since reaching $t$ through $g$ has a path length of 12, this only happens (if at all) after you have processed all nodes at a *closer* distance than 12 from the starting node -- in particular $f$ will also have been processed then.

Depending on whether you add $f$, $g$ or $j$ first, the *first* finite distance we know for $t$ might be 12 -- but we're not actually *visiting* $t$ (and terminating the algorithm) unless its best known distance is *minimal* among all unvisited nodes.

(Also, there's plainly no way to reach $t$ is distance 9, but $s-d-e-f-t$ reaches it in distance 10).

Comment: I see what you did there. First your'e right the other route is 10 (and not 9). Second, I jumped to 't' without checking other distances which was a mistake. Thanks!